# axios local API call in Nuxt Middleware or nuxtServerInit() action returns a 404 error on server side only

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Each time a page loads for the first time in my app it makes an API call to the following URL: `auth/verify`. The call works fine **client side** but returns a 404 error **server side** (*ie. when the user reloads the page*). One alternative that seemed to work was changing the ***url*** config as follows

`url: process.browser ? 'auth/verify' : 'http://localhost:3000/auth/verify'`

This worked fine during development but it caused a server error in production. Here's my code below:

```js
this.$axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'auth/verify',
  data: {
    token: authToken
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.response.data)
})
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

> NOTE: **I'm hosting my node app on a Linux server**. And below are some of the configs in my *nuxt.config.js* file:

```
router: {
  middleware: "auth" /* The middleware making the api call */
},
mode: "universal",
axios: {
  baseURL: "/",
  proxy: true
},
server: {
  host: "0.0.0.0",
  port: 3000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar issue with my nuxt middleware function used for user persistence. The nuxt server will create and render the requested page without taking your external api response into account if you don't return the promise or use async await.

For Example: Here I have a synchronous function that utilizes an axios promise to set vuex data. **You have to return the axios promise.**

```
export default function (context) {
        console.log('Persistence Middleware');
        // No need for request, we have a user object
        if (context.store.state.user) {
            return;
        }

        let token;

        if (process.server) {
            console.log('Persistence Server');
            const headers = context.req.headers.cookie;    
            if (!headers) {
                return;
            }
            token = headers.split('=')[0] === 'token' ? headers.split('=')[1] : null;
        }

        if (process.client) {
            console.log('Persistence Client');
            token = getCookie('token');
        }

        if (token) {
            console.log('Persistence Token', token);
              
            context.$axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
            return context.$axios.$get('/api/v1/userprofile/me')
                .then(res => {

                    console.log({ res }, 'middleware res');
                    context.store.commit('setUser', res);
                 
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log({ err }, 'middleware err');
                });
        }
}
```

Here I utilize async/await without returning.

```
export default async function (context) {
    try {
        console.log('Persistence Middleware');
        // No need for request, we have a user object
        if (context.store.state.user) {
            return;
        }

        let token;

        if (process.server) {
            console.log('Persistence Server');
            const headers = context.req.headers.cookie;
            if (!headers) {
                return;
            }
            token = headers.split('=')[0] === 'token' ? headers.split('=')[1] : null;
        }

        if (process.client) {
            console.log('Persistence Client');
            token = getCookie('token');
        }

        if (token) {
            context.$axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;

            const res = await context.$axios.$get('/api/v1/userprofile/me');
            context.store.commit('setUserData', res);
            console.log(res, 'middleware res');
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log({ error }, 'middleware error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this (with help!) using the options documented [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/):

```js
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || '3000'}/`, // server
      browserBaseURL: '/', // client / browser
    }
  },
```

How it works:

- server: uses `http://localhost` + the `port` (either the `8080` supplied by Azure, or default `3000` in development)
- client: uses the `protocol` and `domain` in the URL

I don't even have an `axios` node in my `nuxt.config.js` - this is the entirety my Axios configuration.

My setup is:

- express back end running at `server/index.js`
- local API at `/api/`
- uses `nuxtServerInit()` to fetch data before rendering the page

Deployment:

- running on Azure
- behind authentication

Scripts:

- build command: `npm run generate`
- startup command: `npm run start`

And it works great... after days of messing around and working all this out.